# Intelligencia UrlRewriter with RegEx is not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
```

which I am expecting should work with this URL:

```
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups/Sub-Groups/Motorcycle-Live.aspx
```

---

However, in my page that this rewritten URL maps to (/Membership/Index.aspx), I am retrieving the `FileName` ("f" in my querystring) and `ParentFileName` ("parentf" in my querystring) to use in a query to get the current page information.

- Value of `FileName` in this case is `Sub-Groups,Motorcycle-Live.aspx` (when I was expecting it to just be `Motorcycle-Live.aspx`)
- Value of 'ParentFileName' in this case is `Member-Groups` (when I was expecting it to be 'Sub-Groups')

---

I have a few other rewrite rules for lower levels, for example:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?f=$1"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$1&amp;f=$2"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$2&amp;f=$3"/>
```

They would work with the following example URLs (respectively):

```
/Membership/Benefits.aspx
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups.aspx
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups/Sub-Groups.aspx
```

In these cases, the `FileName` and `ParentFileName` values are generated as expected. It is only with this '5th-level' page that I am having a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

After removing all of the rewrite rules in my web.config except from this one:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
```

I found that it worked on its own. Then I tried adding them all back in one by one and changing the order until it worked. I finally found that the following order of rules works:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?f=$1"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$2&amp;f=$3"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$1&amp;f=$2"/>
```

So just reversing the order except that I have kept the first rule in the same position.

Comment: What do you get if you use `^/Membership/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)`?

Comment: @Qtax Thanks that's a possibility I'll try it!

Comment: @QTax No just tried and that gives the same result

Comment: Could be one of your other rewrite rules that are messing with it. Are you testing this rewrite by it self? You should do that, or you can try changing all the other `.` to `[^/]`, and adding a `$` at the end of all rules. (Altho it's strange that you are getting a `,` where `/` was, so could be something else.)

Comment: @Qtax Right, I have just tried removing all rules except that one and it works. So yeah it must be something to do with one of the other rules. Just not sure which one! I have already tried switching the order but that just seems to create another problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of all your posted rules, try this:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/([^/]+)$" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?f=$1"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/([^/]+/)*([^/]+)/([^/]+)$" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$2&amp;f=$3"/>
```

This should avoid the rule ambiguity, and has a general rule for arbitrary path depth.

Comment: That's excellent thank you! I was just going to come back to post my solution that I had found, but yours is better! I will still edit my question above with my alternative but I will be using yours. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have another solution you could as well post it as another answer here, maybe it will even get some votes. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution**

After removing all of the rewrite rules in my web.config except from this one:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
```

I found that it worked on its own. Then I tried adding them all back in one by one and changing the order until it worked. I finally found that the following order of rules works:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?f=$1"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$2&amp;f=$3"/>
```

So just reversing the order except that I have kept the first rule in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

**Rearrange your rules:** with such broad patterns `(.+)` you should be starting from longest to shorter:

```
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$3&amp;f=$4"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$2&amp;f=$3"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$1&amp;f=$2"/>
<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?f=$1"/>
```

Alternatively, if oy want to keep the current order, replace all occurrences of `(.+)` in these rules to `([^/]+)`.

**The problem is:** this rule `<rewrite url="^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)" to="/Membership/Index.aspx?parentf=$1&amp;f=$2"/>` will match **ALL** of these URLs:

```
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups.aspx
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups/Sub-Groups.aspx
/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups/Sub-Groups/Motorcycle-Live.aspx
```

And if you have rules in your current order ("shorter" first), the "longer" rules will simply never be evaluated.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions. I have rearranged the order, but then I get 'Index.aspx?parentf=Sub-Groups,Motorcycle-Live.aspx' as the FileName and nothing as the ParentFileName.

Comment: Also, as you may have noticed in a comment above to @Qtax, I have already tried exchanging the '.' characters to '[^/]' but that made no difference!

Comment: @Leah I have tried the pattern on regex testing tool as well as implemented this using IIS URL Rewrite module -- it's working fine - -I have tested it before posting. **There is NO WAY** that this pattern `^/Membership/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)` when matched against this URL `/Membership/Benefits/Member-Groups/Sub-Groups/Motorcycle-Live.aspx` would produce such results. It is only possible if ANOTHER rule handled it. **I STRONGLY suggest** restarting your app/IIS/server or check for other rules that you have. My answer describes the reasons and I am 100% possitive on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe it's because it's running off my local machine, not using IIS. The rewrite rules are added directly into my web.config, not using a server's URL Rewrite module. However, when this site goes live, I will be re-adding the rules via the IIS URL Rewrite module on the server because I have been told Intelligencia UrlRewriter doesn't work with IIS7. So maybe when it goes live it will be fine. But even if that is the case, why does it not work on my local machine?

Comment: @Leah Unfortunately I cannot comment on Intelligencia UrlRewriter -- never heard of it before. In any case -- these rules will have to be rewritten in order to be used by IIS URL Rewrite module. Which OS do you have? If it is Windows Vista or Windows 7 then you can easily install IIS v7 on your PC and run from there. Have you tried restarting?